# How can I select just the 'Create Table' column of SHOW CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql

MySQL `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` has two columns of output, 'Table' and 'Create Table'.  How can I select just the 'Create Table' data?

I've tried

```
mysql> SELECT 'Create Table' FROM (SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename);
```

and

```
mysql> SELECT `Create Table` FROM (SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename);
```

Both result in syntax errors.  I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Formally SHOW statement is a CALL of system stored procedure. Stored procedure (executed by CALL, SHOW, DESC, etc.) cannot be a row source of a query. *How can I select just the 'Create Table' data?* Please do not ask how to continue your attempt to solve some task (unknown to us yet), post the task itself - maybe the solving way selected by you is not optimal... How do you plan to use table's CREATE TABLE?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the result-set in MySQL directly, most connectors can give back a "normal" Result Set for SHOW, so you can use it in that language like a result from a select.

you must check out [INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html), there you find almost every information you need.

Answer (score 0):

What client are you using?  Most language APIs can treat `SHOWs` like `SELECTs` and treat the result as a bunch of rows and columns.  In this  case, it will be one row with 2 columns.

In the case of the MySQL commandline tool, I doubt if you can achieve the goal.  Manually there is `\G`.  Commandline args include --batch, etc., and then use `cut` to get the second column.